# knockout.js html option - show default value when observable is null

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-select

Below is my code to bind a dropdown in ko.js

HTML:

```
 <select data-bind="options: myList, value: _selectedPart , optionsCaption: 'None'"></select>
```

myList is being populated from Database and is successfully displayed with all the values.

I am able to successfully save a value as well.

**Issue**

When I dont select any value, the default value is None.
So, when there is no value(null) for this field in DB - I want to display the default option value as ***"None"***, which is not happening.

```
var _selectedPart = ko.observable();
var itemSelected = // get value from DB;

if (itemSelected) {
    _selectedPart(parnerSelected);// works fine // 
} else {
    // select Default option value as "None"
}
```

I *tried* to check null in HTML. Below code, doesnt work:

```
 <select data-bind="options: myList, value: selectedPart == null ? 'None' : selectedPart "></select>
```

Comment: Can you add your definition of _selectdPartner?

Comment: Sorry, That was a typo. I have edited now. _selectedPart is observable which will bind selected value of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the observable's value to `undefined` to trigger the default `optionsCaption`.

```js
function Sample() {
    var self = this;
  
    this.myList = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    this._selectedPart = ko.observable();
  
    this.selectFromDB = function () {
        // random item to simulate "get from DB"
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.myList.length);
        var value = self.myList[randomIndex];
        self._selectedPart(value);
    };
    this.reset = function () {
        self._selectedPart(undefined);
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new Sample());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: selectFromDB">Select Item</button>
<button data-bind="click: reset">Reset</button>
<br>
<select data-bind="options: myList, value: _selectedPart, optionsCaption: 'None'"></select>
```

You can simplify your code by getting rid of the if/else like this:

```
var itemSelected = // get value from DB;
_selectedPart(itemSelected || undefined);
```

Comment: Thank You Tomalak !  I tried this approach. Still if database contains empty value - The dropdown is selecting first option in the available list , instead of selecting "None". Though default value is None.

Comment: I showed you how to set a select box to the default value. Run the code sample in my answer. It's working. If it does not work for you, then you are doing something different. Find the difference.

Comment: If the value from database is undefined, then the dropdown does not select "None"

Comment: Run my code above. When you set the observable to `undefined` then the default value appears, it's clearly demonstrated. If it does not work for you, you are not really setting the observable to `undefined`, it's as simple as that.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you say where the mistake was, in the end?

Comment: The mistake was in my code. I was adding some other value to the "_selectedPart" somewhere in between. When I debugged, I could identify this. Also, your sample code snippet helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `valueAllowUnset` to your data-bind because `null` is not in the bound array:

```
<select data-bind="options: myList,
                   value: _selectedPart,
                   optionsCaption: 'None',
                   valueAllowUnset: true"></select>
```

See here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements

Comment: Thank You Jonathan. I tried this approach. Still, no luck ... If there is no value saved in database, it should display "None" option as the selected value(default value). But instead, it is displaying the first value in the dropdown list.